# How to host an applet on google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, applet

I've downloaded the google plugin for eclipse, along with the necessary app engine stuff. Now the question is, is it possible to host a pre-made applet using google app engine, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An applet is just a jar or a series of jars that must be downloaded by the browser. Put the jar(s) in your web archive just as you would put a HTML, CSS, image or JS file, and include the markup for the applet in the appropriate page.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html for details.

Comment: I know that, but I'm asking more about the google app engine than the applet hosting itself.

Comment: An applet runs in the browser. Whether it comes from app engine or not doesn't make any difference. Could you elaborate on what you don't understand?

Comment: @Deza Applet JAR file should be stored as a static file (similar to img files) and browser uses the JAR file to run your applet.