# Is there any way to browse local files in Google App Engine other than using FileUpload class?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload

I'm writing a program that will be hosted on GAE that can upload and process local files. The program needs to process the file on the server side, and then return it to the client side. Previously I used JFileChooser for that purpose, but found out that it's not supported in GAE. I did some research and found FileUpload class, but it seems like it can't return the data to the client side. I could just let the user type the path of the file, but that would be just bad usability.

Any ideas are appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE may not support `JFileChooser` directly, but it is apparently [possible to embed applets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940819/how-to-host-an-applet-on-google-app-engine).

Since that is the case:

1. A digitally signed and trusted applet can show a `JFileChooser`.
2. A sand-boxed applet deployed in a Plug-In 2 architecture JRE (e.g. Sun's 1.6.0_10+) can be launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and use the services of the [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) API.  The JNLP API offers the `FileContents` object by way of the `FileOpenService`.  Here is a small [demo. of the file services of the API](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

Comment: Looks a bit complicated but I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Web-apps that access the client file-system *should* be complicated.  It is not for any hack developer to go messing with the file-system on *my* computer.  ;)  Which strategy of 1./2. are you more likely to pursue?

Comment: After some reading I suspected that the wording of my question is not clear: by client I mean my web app, and by server I mean the remote server. So my web app needs to browse and upload the user's local files; it will pass the file to the server for processing, and returns the data to my web app for future operations. I think my wording makes you think that my web app needs to both read from and write to user's local file system. Sorry if that's the case.

Comment: No, even the ability to read local files opens a can of worms in terms of security.

Answer (score -1):

You can't upload files to appengine in the conventional way. There is no filesystem. You have to serialize them into the datastore.

Comment: This is wrong. There is a filesystem; it's just read-only. You can upload files to App Engine the "conventional way".